# Formatting Google Chart Data for Currency

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I'm trying to format the following google charts bottom access to display as currency:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'horizontalBar',
    data: {
        labels: [["California", "2,105 salaries"], ["Texas", "1,461 salaries"], ["New York", "1,253 salaries"], ["Illinois", "946 salaries"], ["Florida", "922 salaries"], ["Ohio", "699 salaries"], ["Pennsylvania", "696 salaries"]],
    datasets: [{
        label: 'National Salary Data',
        data: [100599, 83851, 93192, 87198, 73294, 77068, 81690],
        backgroundColor: [
            'rgba(210, 16, 52, 1)',
            'rgba(210, 16, 52, 1)',
            'rgba(210, 16, 52, 1)',
            'rgba(210, 16, 52, 1)',
            'rgba(210, 16, 52, 1)',
            'rgba(210, 16, 52, 1)',
            'rgba(210, 16, 52, 1)'
        ]
    }]
},
options: {
    postLabelFontSize: 20,
    title: {
        display: true,
        text: ['Employees with a Master of Business Administration (M.B.A.) | degree median salary by job']
    }
}
});
```

I would like the "data" to be formatted with $ and commas like so: $100,599.

I have tried to use something like this but can't get it to work:

```
var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat(
  {prefix: '$', negativeColor: 'red', negativeParens: true});
formatter.format(data, 1);
```

Comment: are you using google charts via some other library? doesn't look like typical _google-vis_ code... (except for the `formatter` portion)

Comment: Agreed with WhiteHat. There's a few similarities to the google visualization API, maybe using ChartWrapper, but the data format and options don't look right, nor does the capitalization on the chart type. A live demo might tell us a lot more about what you're working with and how we can help.